# AWS DMS with AWS MSK(Kafka) CDC transactional changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, cdc, aws-dms, aws-msk

I'm going to use AWS Database Migration Service (DMS) with AWS MSK(Kafka).

I'd like to send all changes within the same transaction into the same partition of Kafka topic - in order to guarantee correct message order(reference integrity)

For this purpose I'm going to enable the following property:

```
IncludeTransactionDetails – Provides detailed transaction information from the source database. This information includes a commit timestamp, a log position, and values for transaction_id, previous_transaction_id, and transaction_record_id (the record offset within a transaction). The default is false. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.Kafka.html
```

Also, as I may see from the same documentation:

```
AWS DMS supports the following two forms for partition keys:

1. SchemaName.TableName: A combination of the schema and table name.

2. ${AttributeName}: The value of one of the fields in the JSON, or the primary key of the table in the source database.
```

I have a question - in case of 'IncludeTransactionDetails = true', will I be able to use 'transaction_id' from event JSON as partition key for MSK(Kafka) migration topic?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says, you can define partition key to group the data
"You also define a partition key for each table, which Apache Kafka uses to group the data into its partitions"